# Keep html buttons at the top of a div

Tags: html, css

The html buttons behave very diferently in firefox and chrome. Take this example http://jsfiddle.net/nuu1bfe2/.

```
<div>
    <button>hi</button>
    <button>hi<br/>you, there</button>
</div>
```

In firefox they are placed in the bottom of the parent but in chrome they are placed in the top. How do I make sure that the buttons are always placed in the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
button{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nuu1bfe2/1/)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `vertical-align: top`:

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.
>
> **top**
>
> Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of the
>   entire line.

```css
div button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>hi</button>
  <button>hi
    <br/>yuo, there</button>
</div>
```

**Reference**

[vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
     button{
     vertical-align:top;
     }
</style>
```

Add css in your html.

Comment: hmm, inline styles are not the best option, external style files with classes are better